# Flutter how to read only bank transaction sms

Tags: regex, string, flutter, dart, string-matching

I want to read and maintain all bank transaction message and to maintain a bank balance

I am able to read all the bank debited and credited message

> my question is that how to find only bank balance string for example

```
BOI -  Rs.5900.00 Credited to your Ac XX1552 on 15-12-19 by UPI ref No.934940203877.Avl Bal 6054.43
```

I want to store just Credited  5900.00 and Avl balance 6054.43

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit naive, but for your given example, you could use

```
\b\d+\.\d+\b
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/dJhdN5/1/). Otherwise, you'd need to specify more input strings.